# babel-loader error Unexpected token, expected "</>/<=/>="

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

**Unlike error for preset. i'm getting error for the closing tag.**

i'm unable create build

i had to use "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript" to resolve existing issue.
where i got error for using

```
{ customer_name, avatar, customerUUID }: row
```

as function argument

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv7XQ.png)
bable.config file

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    plugins: [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements",
        // "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
        // "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
        // "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        // "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator",
        // "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    ],
};
```

here is my webpack.config file

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.js"),
    module: {
        rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
        ],
    },
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
    },
};
```

Comment: try naming your file `.jsx`

Comment: can you please put your webpack file as well?

Comment: yeah i have added the webpack config.

i think issue is similar to [link](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8049)